Efficient calculation of the sum of each entry in two huge vectors
I have two large vectors containing a set of numbers. A typical case would have about 150.000 numbers in each vector ranging from 0 to about 2.000.000. I want to calculate a 3rd vector that contains all the sums of each number in the first vector with each number in the second vector as fast as possible.
My current code:
#include <vector>

namespace
{
    // This function is purely for benchmarking, the numbers are retrieved
    // from other sources in reality, and have the following properties:
    // - The numbers in the vector are sorted
    // - The numbers are guaranteed unique
    std::vector<uint32_t> populate(size_t pRange, size_t pValues)
    {
        std::vector<uint32_t> result;
        std::srand((unsigned)std::time(0));
        result.reserve(pValues);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < pValues; i++)
        {
            uint32_t randomValue = std::rand() % pRange;
            result.push_back(randomValue);
        }
        std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
        return result;
    }
}

// The function to profile, currently complexity O(n^2)
void calculateVectorSums(std::vector<uint32_t> const & pVector1,
                         std::vector<uint32_t> const & pVector2,
                         std::vector<uint8_t> & pResult)
{
    pResult.resize(pVector1.back() + pVector2.back() + 1, 0);
    for (auto nr1 : pVector1)
    {
        for (auto nr2 : pVector2)
        {
            pResult[nr1+nr2] = 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    auto vector1 = populate(2000000, 150000);
    auto vector2 = populate(2000000, 150000);

    // Loop for averaging the profiling numbers
    std::vector<uint8_t> output;
    calculateVectorSums(vector1, vector2, output);
}

The bulk of the time is spent in the pResult[nr1+nr2] = 1; line as expected. And I suspect a huge performance loss happens due to cache misses.
I tried to use a bitset as target buffer, but this was about 2x slower due to the overhead of the bit operations.
I have a burning suspicion that reorganising the order in which the addition is done could lead to a faster overall execution, or perhaps there is a hardware extension (GPU is available) that can accelerate this calculation, but I have very little experience in that field.

Where is performance benchmark? Without measurements taking about performance is useless.

Surprisingly there's an FFT-based algorithm for this: convert the two input vectors to bitvectors and use FFT-based convolution. But it wouldn't be sparse anymore, the time complexity then depends on the input range instead of the input size. Would you be interested anyway?

https://quick-bench.com/q/cYKCoUD6-wylWuqUfcZSK81gY2g

A bit weird to fill a binary array of size MAX1+MAX2 to mark whether the el1+el2 exists, instead of simply filling the uint32_t NxM array of results, but maybe you need it in this form for later. In any case, write a benchmark to measure the performance and then try different approaches. Using GPU kernel (if you have NVIDIA, then deviceQuery to check what's the max num of threads and SMs available to choose the correct block/grid size) is certainly an option, but you need to measure to see if copying the memory host<->device is worth the effort.

@MarekR Sorry, for not adding it and thank you for doing it in my place. The benchmark just spent 25.73Gc in the storing of the result (also reflected in the profile of the disassembly) which is 99% of the total time taken.

@user555045 The initial data is stored in a non-sparse matrix, which I converted to a sparse list for improving the current results. So I would definitely be interested!

@pptaszni I mainly use the binary array for performance reasons as I need the data sorted. I will look into some CUDA samples to see if I can benchmark this, thanks!

Side note: if you use many large sorted list of integers, you may be interested (if you don't already know about it) by a succinct representation like Elias Fano that could have lesser memory footprint (with potentially less cache misses if it fits in some Lx cache) . There exists some C++ implementations (like this one)


I tried to use a bitset as target buffer, but this was about 2x slower due to the overhead of the bit operations.

Here's a different bitwise approach, using a target buffer of uint64_t and instead of setting bit-by-bit, shift the whole thing over (by a distance of some element from the other vector) and OR by it. This not only gets rid of bit-by-bit writes, but also uses the inherent parallelism of a bitwise operation on an uint64_t to do a bunch work at the same time (an amount that depends on the density).
void calculateVectorSumsBitwise(std::vector<uint32_t> const& pVector1,
    std::vector<uint32_t> const& pVector2,
    std::vector<uint8_t>& pResult)
{
    pResult.resize(pVector1.back() + pVector2.back() + 1, 0);
    std::vector<uint64_t> vec1;
    // build initial bitvector
    vec1.resize((pVector1.back() + 63) >> 6);
    for (auto nr1 : pVector1)
    {
        vec1[nr1 >> 6] |= uint64_t(1) << (nr1 & 63);
    }

    std::vector<uint64_t> tmp;
    tmp.resize(1 + ((pVector1.back() + pVector2.back() + 63) >> 6));

    // copy/OR bitvector to all places indicated by pVector2
    for (auto nr2 : pVector2)
    {
        size_t whole_chunk_offset = nr2 >> 6;
        size_t shift_amount = nr2 & 63;
        if (shift_amount) {
            // if the shift count is not zero, shift spreads across two chunks
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) {
                tmp[i + whole_chunk_offset] |= vec1[i] << shift_amount;
                tmp[i + whole_chunk_offset + 1] |= vec1[i] >> (64 - shift_amount);
            }
        }
        else {
            // nice case: shift only by whole word
            for (size_t i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) {
                tmp[i + whole_chunk_offset] |= vec1[i];
            }
        }
    }

    // decompress
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= pVector1.back() + pVector2.back(); i++)
    {
        pResult[i] = (tmp[i >> 6] & (uint64_t(1) << (i & 63))) != 0;
    }
}

On the same quickbench as the other answer (second bar): https://quick-bench.com/q/jvcQyP9OwpVtNgRIwmw4pv1HGP0

I might try to work out the FFT trick that I mentioned in the comments, but it's complicated.
Fun benchmarking story: on my PC, when I tried this bitwise version it looked ~100x as fast as the original approach, instead of ~2x as fast. I was surprised by the discrepancy between that and the result on quickbench until I remembered something about std::rand .. and indeed, on my PC, RAND_MAX = 0x7fff so I was accidentally working with a tiny range of numbers. This bitwise approach benefits massively from a small range, and so the benchmark was ruined. Fun!
This is also why I didn't discover the bugs in the earlier version.

This is a very elegant approach, I implemented both provided answers and am running benchmarks with the typical data I am using in our application. Thanks for the great idea in any case!

I do not see an option to improve your algorithm it terms of logic (improving time complexity).
The only room for improvement I can see is make code more cache friendly.
My idea is to change how iteration is done. Take sub-range from first vector and use it to generate results, then update sub-range::
template<size_t SecSize>
void lessCacheMiss(std::vector<uint32_t> const & pVector1,
                         std::vector<uint32_t> const & pVector2,
                         std::vector<uint8_t> & pResult)
{
    auto it = pVector1.begin();
    for (; it + SecSize < pVector1.end(); it += SecSize) {
        for (auto nr2 : pVector2)
        {
            for (auto nr1 : std::ranges::subrange(it, it + SecSize))
            {
                pResult[nr1+nr2] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto nr2 : pVector2)
    {
        for (auto nr1 : std::ranges::subrange(it, pVector1.end()))
        {
            pResult[nr1+nr2] = 1;
        }
    }
}

Result should be same (please write unit test to prove this code is correct).
And there is significant improvement it execution time:

https://quick-bench.com/q/xtyp6mvP8e94Qxtw7LtYtkKHcKM
Do some experiments of different machines to select best value of SecSize.
There is still space for improvement.
IMO you can try use some parallelism to improve this even more. Problem is how to do it without need of synchronization and avoiding false sharing?

This is the kind of optimisation I had in the back of my mind, but couldn't figure out.  I have to do this calculation for a lot vector sets and those are already parallelized to the amount of cores available, so there is no gain for me in parallelizing the algorithm itself. Thanks!

@oddstar Out of curiosity, how many vector sets are you talking about ?

Typically about 30-40 sets, and we need every permutation. Each vector represents a 3D point cloud (flattened down to a set of indices in a discrete 3D matrix) and these combined structures are used for very fast collision detection.

I would at least consider approaching the problem from the opposite direction.  Assuming 150K numbers between 0-2M, the O(N^2) loop is performing 22.5B computations to determine if 4M sums exist.  That's, on average, 5625 computations per sum.  If we attempt to answer whether a particular sum exists, it is possible to be more efficient.
I have implemented a working solution that is 30x faster than the naive O(n^2) loop posted in the question.  An additional advantage is that the main loop to compute whether a specific sum exists can be parallelized in a cache efficient manner.
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

namespace {
// This function is purely for benchmarking, the numbers are retrieved
// from other sources in reality, and have the following properties:
// - The numbers in the vector are sorted
// - The numbers are guaranteed unique
std::vector<uint32_t> populate(size_t pRange, size_t pValues) {
    std::vector<uint32_t> result;
    std::srand((unsigned)std::time(0));
    result.reserve(pValues);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < pValues; i++) {
        uint32_t randomValue = std::rand() % pRange;
        result.push_back(randomValue);
    }
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
}   // namespace

// The function to profile, currently complexity O(n^2)
void calculateVectorSums(std::vector<uint32_t> const& pVector1,
                         std::vector<uint32_t> const& pVector2,
                         std::vector<uint8_t>& pResult) {
    pResult.resize(pVector1.back() + pVector2.back() + 1, 0);
    for (auto nr1 : pVector1) {
        for (auto nr2 : pVector2) {
            pResult[nr1 + nr2] = 1;
        }
    }
}

// note: indices could be used instead of iterators
using Range = std::pair<std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator, std::vector<uint32_t>::const_iterator>;

bool exactSumExists(uint32_t target, Range rng1, Range rng2) {
    auto it1 = rng1.first;
    auto it2 = rng2.second - 1;
    while (it1 != rng1.second && it2 >= rng2.first) {
        auto sum = *it1 + *it2;
        if (sum < target) {
            ++it1;
        } else if (sum > target) {
            --it2;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// For each sum, ret[candidate] contains the range within 'v' that could potentially be used to achieve that sum.
std::vector<Range> calculatePotentialRange(const std::vector<uint32_t>& v, uint32_t otherMin, uint32_t otherMax) {
    auto maxSum = v.back() + otherMax;
    auto ret    = std::vector<Range>(maxSum + 1);

    // otherMax = 2M, [100, 100K, 1M, 2M] =>
    //      ret[0..2'000'100].first = it(100),
    //      ret[2'000'101..2'100'000].first = it(100K),
    //      ret[2'100'001..3'000'000].first = it(1M)
    //      ret[3'000'001..4'000'000].first = it(2M)
    for (uint32_t val = 0; val <= otherMax + v.front(); ++val) {
        ret[val].first = v.begin();
    }
    for (auto curr = v.begin(), next = curr + 1; next != v.end(); ++curr, ++next) {
        auto from = *curr + otherMax + 1;
        auto to   = next != v.end() ? (*next + otherMax) : maxSum;
        for (auto val = from; val <= to; ++val) {
            ret[val].first = next;
        }
    }

    // otherMin = 5, [100, 100K, 1M, 2M] =>
    //      ret[0..104].second = it(100) ==> no possible range
    //      ret[105..100'004].second = ++it(100)
    //      ret[100'005..1'000'004].second = ++it(100K)
    //      ret[1'000'005..2'000'004].second = ++it(1M)
    //      ret[2'000'005..4'000'000].second = ++it(2M)
    for (uint32_t val = 0; val < otherMin + v.front(); ++val) {
        ret[val].second = v.begin();
    }
    for (auto curr = v.begin(), next = curr + 1; curr != v.end(); ++curr, ++next) {
        auto from = *curr + otherMin;
        auto to   = next != v.end() ? (*next + otherMin - 1) : maxSum;
        for (auto val = from; val <= to; ++val) {
            ret[val].second = next;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void calculateVectorSums2(std::vector<uint32_t> const& v1,
                          std::vector<uint32_t> const& v2,
                          std::vector<uint8_t>& result) {
    auto rng1   = calculatePotentialRange(v1, v2.front(), v2.back());
    auto rng2   = calculatePotentialRange(v2, v1.front(), v1.back());
    auto maxSum = v1.back() + v2.back();

    result.assign(maxSum + 1, 0);   // note: assign() is correct, resize() is not

    // Note: loop can be parallelized
    for (uint32_t candidate = 0; candidate <= maxSum; ++candidate) {
        auto exists       = exactSumExists(candidate, rng1[candidate], rng2[candidate]);
        result[candidate] = exists;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    auto v1 = populate(2'000'000, 150'000);
    auto v2 = populate(2'000'000, 150'000);

    std::vector<uint8_t> result1, result2;

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    calculateVectorSums(v1, v2, result1);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    calculateVectorSums2(v1, v2, result2);
    auto t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << (result1 == result2) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t3 - t2) << '\n';
    return 0;
}


Note: This algorithm is worse than the O(n^2) loop when the density of #'s in the range is low.  For example, if there were only 10K numbers between 0-2M, this algorithm would be slower than the O(n^2) loop.

Thanks for this approach. I had tried a reverse implementation, but also quite a naive one, the range idea is excellent! There is a huge variation in the data, but it are mainly the larger sets that give performance hits, so switching algorithm depending on the dataset is definitely feasible.
